# BibLaTeX Tutorial: May I show you my example *before* publishing it

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to do a BibLaTeX tutorial (Video, YouTube) with a step-by-step explanation using TeXmaker and also the command line. Would it be appropriate to show you guys here my example before I do the tutorial? I am not 100 % sure if I understand all the encoding subjects correctly.

Comment: Hi! I have a suggestion: how about talking with the chatroom regulars? It's a way of having almost instant feedback. `:)` http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Comment: @PauloCereda Agreed. Actually I find the chat function here very confusing. As soon as I have prepared my example document I will try to contact the "regulars".

Comment: cfr has done some stuff, at gL we have the [wichtige Hinweise](http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html). I wanted to redo the wikiboks-page, but who has the time.

Comment: Remember, if something changes (and biblatex can change quite a bit with one blink of the eye) you need to update. A text-based solution is updated fast, but a video? Please have a look at http://www.komascript.de/node/1938

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the hints. Let's see if you will be happy with my solution. It's just a hobby and I like it. I already have made a installation tutorial that is quite "successfull": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4uIAOPq1UE (newest) OR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxKtwdob2RQ (most popular)

Comment: "Table of contets"

Comment: I notice that in your video you explicitly change the font encoding. Maybe it would be nicer to just tell the viewer how to figure out her font encoding and what `fontenc` setting to use. I would also recommend UTF-8 as default over ISO-8859-1. Normally it is not necessary to give `bibencoding` when `.tex` and `.bib` file have the same encoding.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the feedback. The bibencoding option was on purpose to raise awareness. It's just a option, I don't fight about it. I tried to get some feedback here before I make the tutorial, you can see that it was not easy.

Comment: Mhh, my main problem with how you do it that you simply give the `bibencoding` option without explaining it any further. In your case, the option is superfluous, but if people have a UTF-8 document and `.bib` file and then watch only the `biblatex` part of your video they might end up with a mess if they use `bibencoding=latin1`. In general it seems that most people watching these tutorials don't look up every option used, but simply copy and paste and expect things to work.

Comment: @moewe It's a lot of effort to generate a tutorial (at least for me) -- what you see takes hours of "work"/free time. **But yes, it could be improved.**. And I get your point about the encoding stuff. I still (just an opinion) think that the "barrier to entry" to `biblatex` and `biber` is lower when people watch my video. So far I get goog feedback. Name a better tutorial (no matter which format) and I link it in the description of the video.

Comment: I have no doubt that it is a lot of work to do a tutorial (a video tutorial even more so!). And I don't mean to belittle the work you have done. I was just just trying to point out something unusual (the explicit change of the encoding as well as `bibencoding`) that I found unfortunate, for the reasons I hopefully explained well enough above. There are many tutorials out there and they all have their strengths and weaknesses (some more, some less) and they all focus on different things and do that on different levels.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *here* would be a good fit as meta-type questions typically ask questions about the main site. So questions here would be with regards to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com), which yours seems to not be.

If your aim was to ask on the main site, then it seems like you don't really have a question (at the moment)... you just want some feedback on a possible tutorial.

Rephrase your current tutorial in the form of a *question* and then post it, together with your tutorial (with code and pictures and links and such) as an *answer*. That's more like it.

Comment: I agree. Just didn't knew where to ask. I just didn't want to ask on the main site a question if I can ask a specific question on the main site :). Vote to close if think that's in order - I will delete it asap.

Comment: But if @Dr.ManuelKuehner does this, they'll be no indication that the point is to garner feedback on the *answer*, will there? I think chat really would be ideal for this as Paulo suggested.